FastAPI Depends(func) returns a dataclass but the typing is not right
I created a dependency function to verify token in the header and return info from the token.
async def require_auth(res:Response, cred: HTTPAuthorizationCredentials = Depends(HTTPBearer(auto_error=True))):
    try:
        # 3rd-party service verify the token and reutrn user info
        decoded = ...
    except:
       raise HTTPException(...)
    return DecodedUser(**decoded)

here decoded is a dict contains user info and DecodedUser is a dataclass:
@dataclass(slots=True)
class DecodedUser:
    id: str
    email: str
    ...

but when using this in api:
@app.get('/')
async def hello(user=Annotated[DecodedUser, Depends(require_auth)]):
    user.id  # this line

vscode pylance shows a red line under the id and complains: Cannot access member "id" for type "type[Annotated]" \n Member "id" is unknown,
and hover on the user shows its type is type[DecodedUser], which supposed to be DecodedUser.
What am I doing wrong?

You wrote = instead of :
Replace this
user=Annotated[DecodedUser, Depends(require_auth)]

by:
user: Annotated[DecodedUser, Depends(require_auth)]


lol, I must be blind. Thanks! Though the document is a bit confusing. So use : with Annotated and = when just Depends().
